# Proof of Lipschitz continuous for a fuction with two variables

Tags: optimization, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have the following function
$f(x,y) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + a x^2 + y^2}.$

Could you suggest the way to prove it Lipschitz continuous as well as the value of $L?$

Thank you very much.

Comment: One way to show a function is Lipschitz is to show that its gradient is bounded.

Comment: We need to prove it upper bounded or lower bounded, may I ask?

Comment: Lower bounds won't help you. Show it is bounded above

Comment: is $a$ positive?

Comment: It could be positive and negative.